# Padding an entire column in an html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two columns in a table.  Without explicitly specifying a column width, I want to allow a bit of space between the left column and the right.  I know I can do this by setting the padding-right style on each left cell, but is there some way to just specify it once so it applies to all cells in that column?  I don't want to add a "spacer" column, because then the html is no longer reflecting the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp) css selector:

```
td:first-child {padding-right:20px;}
```

This will select the first `td` in each row.